# Caching bitmap in android

Tags: android

Kind of new to caching of bitmap for android. Would like to ask a few questions. Do you guys have sample code of caching an image and retriving an image from cache. How do the codes know once the cache is being overridden?

Comment: And what kind of cache is it you want? A memory cache for decoded images or a file cache for downloaded images? (Or parhaps a combo of them both?)

Comment: wow? Whats the different between a memory cache and a file cache? i'm using mainly for caching image downloaded from web so that i can pass around activity

Comment: If you store a file as a file cache it will be written on nand memory and it will be stored if you close application :), but that will not happen for a memory cache, since all the objects are marked for garbage collection if app is closed

Comment: Hey man thanks! Do you have any tutorial for memory cache? Most likely will use memory cache as it should only be stored on runtime :). If user reopen the bitmap might have been changed